# Unable to send post request from .Net application it works fine with Chrome RESTClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpwebrequest

Why I am not able to send POST request using the following command and some other code similar to it. Where as when I send same request using Mozilla browser's RESTClient it works fine. This is only for a server's simulator deployed on LAN/even on my local machine. with Live server it is working fine.

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.220.12:5000"); // this is my system's local ip
byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes("hello");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";// i tried it with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as well
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Flush();
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
Console.ReadKey();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

By testing it on server, I saw there is a message for successful receiving of the request but it does not show the data received from the above code whereas it shows the data from RESTclient.

What could be the possible reason. Is there any firewall the is not allowing to send postdata from .net library to simulator?

This is the same response for un formatted xml, I don't see anything wrong with the xml (same copy of what I am sending through RESTclient).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what content type does the server expects the request to be. If it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (key=value pairs) you could simplify your code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key2", "value2" },
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://192.168.220.12:5000", values);
    string resultStr = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
    ...
}
```

If you want to POST XML then:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/xml";
    string xml = "<foo>Bar</foo>";
    string result = client.UploadString("http://192.168.220.12:5000", xml);
}
```

So as you can see, it will all depend on what does your server side script expects.

Comment: content type is an xml e.g. "<?xml version='1.0'?><!DOCTYPE svc_init SYSTEM 'MLP_SVC_INIT_320.DTD'><svc_init ver='3.3.0'><hdr ver='3.3.0'><client><id>polaris</id><pwd>polaris123</pwd></client></hdr><slir ver='3.3.0' res_type='SYNC'><msid type='MSISDN'>96893111157</msid><gsm_net_param><neid><vmscid></vmscid></neid></gsm_net_param><trans_id>6</trans_id><eqop><max_loc_age>3600</max_loc_age></eqop></slir></svc_init>"

Comment: Alright, so what happened when you tried my second code example to send this XML to the server?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: your code gives same error on server i.e. 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at com.pw.simulator.mlc.Creader.run(Creader.java:42)

This is the same response for unformatted xml, I don't see anything wrong with the xml (same copy of what I am sending through RESTclient).

Do I have to do some changes to xml or while creating byte [] from it?

Comment: I don't know what you have to do. I don't know what does your server side script do nor how it expects the request to be formatted. Without this information I cannot help you.

Comment: just now I checked the code with actual MLC server (not simulator) and it work fine. still don't know why this code is not working with simulator whereas RESTClient is working fine? where there can be a firewall setting that is not allowing requests from .net code?